# Relacionamento é igual a 0

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Sou novato em relacionamento em core data e não sei o que está acontecendo.
Tenho um relacionamento muitos para muitos entre a entidade Noticias e Amigos conforme mostrado a baixo:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

criei NSManagedobject Subclass mas não alterei nada (não sei se isso é essencial para que funcione o relacionamento) e também acho que não é necessário popular este relacionamento já que as duas entidades já possuem dados.E eu descobri que o relacionamento está vazio utilizando:

```
let predicateDenuncia = NSPredicate(format: "any amigos.amizade.@count == %d" , 0)
```

e também tentei :

```
let predicateDenuncia = NSPredicate(format: "any amigos.@count == %d" , 0)
```

Desse jeito descobri a meu relacionamento está retornando vazio , alguém ai sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?
Obrigado.

Comment: Coloca o `NSFetchRequest` completo, ficará mais fácil de depurar.

Comment: Estava faltando eu popular os relacionamentos com dados eu tinha pulado esta etapa rs mas obrigado pela ajuda!valeu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver este problema....como nunca tinha mexido com relacionamentos em Core Data não sabia que tinha que popular o relacionamento rs agora está dando tudo certo !